# Sorting Result state taking very long time

Tags: mysql, innodb, sorting

I am using a MySQL 5.1.69-log DB for analysis purpose.

I've designed my database in a star schema. All tables are using InnoDB.
 My `innodb_buffer_pool_size=2Gb`

This is the query I am running :

```
select
     `dw_dimension_criteria`.`id` as `c0`,
     count(distinct `dw_fact_program_attendance`.`client_id`) as `m0`
from
     `dw_dimension_criteria` as `dw_dimension_criteria`,
     `dw_fact_program_attendance` as `dw_fact_program_attendance`
where
     `dw_fact_program_attendance`.`criteria_id` = `dw_dimension_criteria`.`id`
group by `dw_dimension_criteria`.`id`;
```

The *EXPLAIN* gives the following :

```
+----+-------------+----------------------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                      | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref                                     | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dw_dimension_criteria      | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY      | 2       | NULL                                    |      1 | Using index | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dw_fact_program_attendance | ref   | criteria_id   | criteria _id | 2       | clarity_nevada.dw_dimension_criteria.id | 417669 |             |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+-------------+
```

and the *SHOW PROFILE* command the following :

```
+----------------------+-----------+
| Status               | Duration  |
+----------------------+-----------+
| starting             |  0.000117 |
| checking permissions |  0.000035 |
| checking permissions |  0.000009 |
| Opening tables       |  0.000022 |
| System lock          |  0.000004 |
| Table lock           |  0.000011 |
| init                 |  0.000032 |
| optimizing           |  0.000012 |
| statistics           |  0.000045 |
| preparing            |  0.000017 |
| executing            |  0.000043 |
| Sorting result       |  0.000005 |
| Sending data         | 12.847928 |
| end                  |  0.000103 |
| removing tmp table   |  0.000016 |
| end                  |  0.000016 |
| query end            |  0.000005 |
| freeing items        |  0.000114 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000003 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000097 |
| cleaning up          |  0.000012 |
+----------------------+-----------+
```

I do not understand those 12 seconds. I do not understand if it belongs to *Sorting Result* or *Sending Data*. I tried adjusting `sort_buffer_size` but with no flagrant success. The fact table count about 7 millions rows.

Where should I look to drop those 12 seconds to a more reasonable time ?

Comment: Is there a foreign key `dw_fact_program_attendance(race_id)` that `REFERENCES dw_dimension_criteria(id)`?

Comment: And is there a typo or different naming? The query shows `race_id` but the explain shows index `criteria_is`

Comment: have you tried adding index on  dw_dimension_criteria`.`id`?

Comment: About the "Sending data" state, read this answer: [What does it mean when mysql is in the state “Sending data”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347193/what-does-it-mean-when-mysql-is-in-the-state-sending-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a foreign key from `dw_fact_program_attendance(criteria_id)` that `REFERENCES dw_dimension_criteria(id)`, there is no need to join the two tables (but the optimizer is not yet smart enough to understand that.) You can have only one table and `GROUP BY criteria_id`:

```
SELECT
     a.criteria_id AS c0,
     COUNT(DISTINCT a.client_id) AS m0
FROM
     dw_fact_program_attendance AS a
GROUP BY
     a.criteria_id ;
```

An index on `(criteria_id, client_id)` would help efficiency.

Comment: Applying the composite key helped a lot. It went from about 12 to about 6 seconds. Thank you.